# REST API return JSON object using factory and interface

Tags: module, rest-api, factory, interface

I am trying to create a simple module to return JSON data, if i returned string or array it will return the targeted data, but i can't return JSON object with key value

when i return the interface it will return error 500, the second time i refresh it will keep loading forever. so i have to restart apache to work.

so my code, first the product interface:

```
<?php
namespace MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data;

interface ProductInterface
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId();
    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id);

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name);
}
```

the used model:

```
<?php

namespace MzTest\ApiTool\Model\Data;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data\ProductInterface;

class Product extends DataObject implements ProductInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        $this->getId();
        return $this->getData('id');
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        return $this->setData('id', $id);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getData('name');
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        return $this->setData('name', $name);
    }
}
```

and in the method:

```
/**
 * @api
 * @param int $id
 * @return \MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data\ProductInterface
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function show($id)
{
    /** @var \MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productInterface */
    $productInterface = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();

    try {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);

        $productInterface->setId($product->getId());
        $productInterface->setSku($product->getSku());
        $productInterface->setName($product->getName());

        return $productInterface;
       
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $th) {
        throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', $id);
    }
}
```

---

Update:

ProductRepositoryInterface:

```
<?php
namespace MzTest\ApiTool\Api;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $id
     * @return \MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function show($id);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Searching I found the issue was from serializing the object, I was extening `DataObject` in class `Product`. and it doesn't have `__toArray` method.

the solution was to extend `Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject`

Answer (score 0):

Update:

ProductRepositoryInterface:

```
<?php
namespace MzTest\ApiTool\Api;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $id
     * @return string
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function show($id);

}
```

You need to encode the API response and then return like below.

```
    /**
     * @api
     * @param int $id
     * @return \MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        /** @var \MzTest\ApiTool\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productInterface */
        $productInterface = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
    
        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($id);
    
            $productInterface->setId($product->getId());
            $productInterface->setSku($product->getSku());
            $productInterface->setName($product->getName());
            
            //return json_encode($productInterface); /*Modified this line in your code.*/

echo json_encode($productInterface); exit; /*Modified this line in your code.*/

           
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $th) {
            throw NoSuchEntityException::singleField('id', $id);
        }

}
```

Comment: it does return `"{}"`with quotation

Comment: can you share your interface file in the question or refer to this return string line? please check this screenshot. https://tinyurl.com/2eukhlks

Comment: I have again updated the return line in my answer. can you try that?

Comment: I have updated my code, and  have tested `echo` and exit, but i can't set the headers to to json

Comment: You can set the JSON in headers using the postman tool like this screenshot. https://tinyurl.com/2ls5mcka Also I have made a change in the interface class for return line, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Now i have modified  * @return string line in you interface class.